# Adding sudoer for all but root

Tags: linux, command-line, php, sudo, cpanel

Here is the base of my problem: I would like to add `sudo` rights to a user, but not to use it as `root` for security reasons.

I have a PHP script needing to run a command (`drush`) through `exec()`. However, the PHP is run as a user and I want the command to be executed as another user. This is required because if not, there is a permission problem to write in the other user's directory.

The `drush` command itself works, I've made it available to all users.

The current user (A) is a cPanel reseller that created the other account/user (B).

I can run `exec('ls -la')` as user A and it will return the CWD's contents as long as we are in user A's home directory. The same code with added `sudo` fails as user A is not in the sudoers list.

The final command downloads files to user B's directory and looks like:
`'<pwd> | sudo -S -u <usrB> drush dl drupal <irrelevant options>'`

`-S` is supposed to automatically execute the command as user B using his password.

Running the exact same command as root works perfectly.

I wanted to know if there is a way to add user A to the sudoers without access as root, and if that would be safe to prevent potential security flaws. If it isn't possible, are there alternatives? I saw one could exclude directories from sudoers using `!`, but then I realized that this would be quite flawed.

Please note that I'm a developer, so even though I know some basics, I'm not a pro. Server is running CentOS 6.5, WHM/cPanel, and I have root access if needed. The idea is that a one-time setup will prevent configuration upon new user creation.

Comment: `sudoers` has the ability to restrict the `sudo` command to very specific commands. Look at the man page for it.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 6.5 has examples in the default sudoers file.. assuming the user is "user_a" and the command you want to run is ls, but only on the local host

```
user_a localhost=/bin/ls
```

if you want multiple commands separate the commands with a comma

for more information man sudoers has examples. http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html

Comment: This partially answers my question and could actually be enough once I get it to work. I tried adding `user_a ALL=/bin/ls,/usr/bin/drush` using `visudo` and then just `sudo ls -la` and it doesn't work. I also tripled checked this is executed as `user_a`.

Comment: can you type sudo -l as user_a and paste the result?

Comment: There is nothing in the output. The command before that is `id -u -n` and it gives me user_a as a result.

Comment: I just connected through SSH (instead of PHP for the other tests) as user_a and ran the same command, except this time they appear like they should, so that's a first problem. When I run the full command (see question), it tells me I can't execute `'/usr/bin/drush dl drupal <etc.>` as user_b, which seems normal but is problematic; I had thought the sudo part of it would override that.